# string count all strings giving incorrect answer in R

Tags: r, tidyr, stringr, stringi

```
      A<-  c('C-C-C','C-C', 'C-C-C-C')

      library(stringr)
      B<- str_count(A, "C-C")
      df<- data.frame(A,B)

     A        B (expected)   B(actual) 
   C-C-C      2              1
   C-C        1              1
   C-C-C-C    3              2
```

I am trying to count all the transitions, however, I am getting the wrong answer. Can someone suggest how to fix this?

Comment: You expect that the strings are allowed to *overlap*, what is not the case.

Comment: If overlap is allowed, is it not simpler to count the `-`? Alternatively, `strsplit` based on your expectation and count the valid parts. E.g. `strsplit(x = "C-C-C-C-C-C", split = "C-C", fixed = TRUE)` returns three parts: `[1] ""  "-" "-"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect that the strings are allowed to *overlap*, what is not the case. For that you need to make a *Lookahead*.

```
str_count(A, "C(?=-C)")
#[1] 2 1 3
```

or count the `-`:

```
str_count(A, "-")
#[1] 2 1 3
```

or in *base*:

```
lengths(gregexpr("C(?=-C)", A, perl=TRUE))
#[1] 2 1 3
```

Answer (score 0):

`str_count` wraps `stringi::stri_count`. While it does not allow you to specify optional arguments, you could just call `stri_count` directly.

```
stringi::stri_count(str = A, pattern = "C-C", fixed = stringi::stri_opts_fixed(overlap = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `gsub` with `nchar` in `base R`

```
nchar(gsub("[^-]+", "", A))
#[1] 2 1 3
```